# How to make 8-bit bitmap appear as monochrome in C++?

Tags: c++, image, bitmap, gdi

When I set up and create a 24-bit bitmap like this:

```
   //fileheader
    BITMAPFILEHEADER* bf = new BITMAPFILEHEADER;
    bf->bfType = 0x4d42;
    bf->bfSize = 6054400 + 54;
    bf->bfOffBits = 54;

    //infoheader
    BITMAPINFOHEADER* bi = new BITMAPINFOHEADER;
    bi->biSize = 40;
    bi->biWidth = 2752;
    bi->biHeight = -733;
    bi->biPlanes = 1;
    bi->biBitCount = 24;
    bi->biCompression = 0;
    //bi->biSizeImage = 6054400;
    bi->biXPelsPerMeter = 2835;
    bi->biYPelsPerMeter = 2835;
    bi->biClrUsed = 0;
    bi->biClrImportant = 0;

    pFrame->GetImage(m_imageData);

    //
    //create bitmap...
    //(hbit is a global variable)

    BITMAPINFO* bmi;
    bmi = (BITMAPINFO*)bi; 
    HDC hdc = ::GetDC(NULL);

    hbit = CreateDIBitmap(hdc, bi, CBM_INIT, m_imageData, bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
```

I get an output image like this:
[image: image1]

But when I change bitcount from 24 to 8 (which also allows for 3x image size, allowing me to go from 733 width to the image's natural width of 2200), I get an image like this (along with a lot of instability):

[image: image2]

My output looks like this:

```
    BITMAP* bi = new BITMAP;
    CBitmap bmp;
    bmp.Attach(hbit);
    CClientDC dc(pWnd);
    CDC bmDC;
    bmDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
    CBitmap *pOldbmp = bmDC.SelectObject(&bmp);
    bmp.GetBitmap(bi);
    dc.BitBlt(384,26,bi->bmWidth/3,bi->bmHeight,&bmDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);
    //note: if bitcount is 8, height and width need to be /3, 
          //if 24, only width gets /3 
    bmDC.SelectObject(pOldbmp);

    //explicitly delete everything just to be safe
    delete bi;
    DeleteObject(bmp);
    DeleteObject(dc);
    DeleteObject(pOldbmp);
    DeleteObject(bmDC);
```

**So my questions are:**

- Why is this happening when I switch from 24 to 8?
- Is there an easy way to output the image as monochrome rather than color?

**One last thing:**

My coworker wrote this function a long time ago for a similar issue, but he said I may be able to use it.  I can't get it to work, unfortunately:

```
void CopyMono8ToBgrx(byte* pDestBlue, byte* pDestGreen, byte *pDestRed, byte* pDestAlpha)
    {
        byte*               pSrc;
        byte*               pSrcEnd;

        pSrc = ( byte* ) m_imageData;
        pSrcEnd = pSrc + ( 2752*2200 );

        while ( pSrc < pSrcEnd )
        {
            byte data = *pSrc;

            *pDestBlue  = data;
            *pDestGreen = data;
            *pDestRed   = data;
            *pDestAlpha = 255;  // alpha is always 255 (fully opaque)

            pSrc++;
            pDestBlue   += 4;
            pDestGreen  += 4;
            pDestRed    += 4;
            pDestAlpha  += 4;
        }
    }
```

Comment: looks like your colormap (palette) may be screwed up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8 bit per pixel images are assuming a color palette following `BITMAPINFOHEADER` structure (see [`BITMAPINFO::bmiColors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). If you make the palette to be 256 gray shades, the image is going to me 8 bpp grayscale. Now it's color with random colors on it.

The function `CopyMono8ToBgrx` you quoted creates full color bitmap, with gray individual pixels (R=G=B).

Comment: So how would I go about making the palette 256 gray shades?

Comment: Have a look here: [Drawing on 8bpp grayscale bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142349/drawing-on-8bpp-grayscale-bitmap-unmanaged-c/3143766#3143766)

Answer (score 7):

You should create a color pallete. Try this:

```
struct BITMAPINFO256 {
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmiHeader;
    RGBQUAD bmiColors[256];
} bmi;
memset(&bmi, 0, sizeof(BITMAPINFO256));
bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = 40;
bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = 2752;
bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -733;
bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 8;
bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = 0;
bmi.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 2835;
bmi.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 2835;
bmi.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 256;
bmi.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    bmi.bmiColors[i].rgbRed   = i;
    bmi.bmiColors[i].rgbGreen = i;
    bmi.bmiColors[i].rgbBlue  = i;
}
```

And then when you call `CreateDIBitmap` it will become:

```
hbit = CreateDIBitmap(hdc, &bmi.bmiHeader, CBM_INIT, m_imageData, (BITMAPINFO*)&bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
```

Also note that you should be careful to also increase the offset in your `BITMAPFILEHEADER` so that it it expresses that there is color pallete defined before the actual pixels data (yesterday I was having hard time because of this, see [Creating 8bpp bitmap with GDI and saving it as a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859138/creating-8bpp-bitmap-with-gdi-and-saving-it-as-a-file)):

```
bf->bfOffBits = 54 + sizeof(RGBQUAD)*256;
```

And to that function that your coworker wrote: It's better to use [Luminance](http://www.songho.ca/dsp/luminance/luminance.html) to convert colors to gray-scale equivalents:
[image]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi, I am using this code and it gives grayscale image, but the image is flipped vertically. I am using positive height as negative height gives a plain black output. Please tell me how to get the correct image.

Comment: @Khushboo: Post it as a new question, provide more details and also put there a link to this answer and write it that the solution is based on this. It's hard to say what could be the problem like this :)