# grayscale hbitmap with python ctypes

Tags: python, winapi, bitmap, ctypes, gdi

I have PIL images that I am trying to convert to grayscale HBitmap in ctypes. I have minimal knowledge of ctypes, C, or dealing with HBITMAPs.  I cobbled together code from various sources, such as

1. [Drawing on 8bpp grayscale bitmap (unmanaged C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142349/drawing-on-8bpp-grayscale-bitmap-unmanaged-c/3143766#3143766)
2. http://d.hatena.ne.jp/chrono-meter/20090905/p3

This is what I have so far. First, I initialized the required headers:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

class BITMAPINFOHEADER(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('biSize', wintypes.DWORD),
        ('biWidth', wintypes.LONG),
        ('biHeight', wintypes.LONG),
        ('biPlanes', wintypes.WORD),
        ('biBitCount', wintypes.WORD),
        ('biCompression', wintypes.DWORD),
        ('biSizeImage', wintypes.DWORD),
        ('biXPelsPerMeter', wintypes.LONG),
        ('biYPelsPerMeter', wintypes.LONG),
        ('biClrUsed', wintypes.DWORD),
        ('biClrImportant', wintypes.DWORD),
        ]

class RGBQUAD(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('rgbRed', ctypes.c_byte),
        ('rgbGreen', ctypes.c_byte),
        ('rgbBlue', ctypes.c_byte),
        ('rgbReserved', ctypes.c_byte),
    ]

class BITMAPINFO(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('bmiHeader', BITMAPINFOHEADER),
        ('bmiColors', ctypes.POINTER(RGBQUAD))
    ]

w,h=image.size

bmi = BITMAPINFO()
bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = ctypes.sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)
bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = w
bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = h
bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1
bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 8
bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = 0 
bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0 

elems=(RGBQUAD*256)()
bmi.bmiColors=ctypes.cast(elems,ctypes.POINTER(RGBQUAD))


for i in range(256):
    bmi.bmiColors[i].rgbRed=i
    bmi.bmiColors[i].rgbGreen=i
    bmi.bmiColors[i].rgbBlue=i
    bmi.bmiColors[i].rgbReserved=0
```

Then, I created my hbitmap:

```
ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary('C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll')
gdi=ctypes.WinDLL('C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll')

hDC = gdi.CreateCompatibleDC(0)

try:
    dataptr = ctypes.c_void_p()
    result = gdi.CreateDIBSection(hDC, ctypes.byref(bmi), 0,
                                  ctypes.byref(dataptr), None, 0)

    hOldBitmap = gdi.SelectObject(hDC, result)
    try:
        buf = imagebytes
        wintypes.memmove(dataptr, buf, len(buf))
    finally:
        gdi.SelectObject(hDC, hOldBitmap)

finally:
    gdi.DeleteDC(hDC)

hbitmap = result
```

I am uploading these HBITMAPs to some projector via separate lines of code in Python. The HBITMAPs I created seem to work partially, in that I can successfully define spatial patterns to be projected. I have problems instead with getting graded pixel intensity. Specifically, pixels show up as black if I set values from 0-127, and white if I set values from 128-255, with no gradations. These lead to me suspect that it is a problem with setting the RGB color palette.

I have directly saved the PIL image files to .bmp and verified that they have graded intensity values. Perhaps it would be easier to troubleshoot if I had a way to also save the HBITMAP output at the end to .bmp, but at this stage I am only checking these HBITMAPs by directly uploading to my projector.

I have also tried screwing with the code that defines the color palette, for example:

```
bmi.bmiColors[i].rgbRed=9999
```

or:

```
bmi.bmiColors[i].rgbsRed=i
```

But none of these seem to have any effect on the output of my projector. I can still set images accurately, just with no graded pixel intensities.

Comment: `HBITMAP` is a struct data type, it's not a file format. Can you give some example or link?

Comment: my apologies, I meant to just say the HBITMAP handle, which I pass in python to my projector system.

Comment: *"I was not able assign the color palette values"* - How exactly? Did it fail at runtime? Did it succeed, but not produce the desired result? There are a few issues with the code: You aren't setting the *biCompression* member to `BI_RGB` (this is required). You are setting the *biSizeImage* to a non-zero value, but it's the wrong value, as it doesn't account for scanline alignment to `DWORD` boundaries. And then, `BITMAPINFO` is of variable size (see [Why do some structures end with an array of size 1?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040826-00/?p=38043) for an explanation).

Comment: @IInspectable I have now set _biCompression_ and _biSizeImage_ both to 0. However, I have too little knowledge of C++ to know how to proceed re: `BITMAPINFO`. I understand that BITMAPINFO is variable size because of the _bmiColors_ (correct?). Does this mean I have to properly allocate memory for BITMAPINFO? I do not know how to do this in ctypes, I could not find functions corresponding to alloca() or offsetof(), as I saw used in your answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142349/drawing-on-8bpp-grayscale-bitmap-unmanaged-c/3143766#3143766

Answer (score 0):

@OP: What broke your python code was the line:

```py
('bmiColors', ctypes.POINTER(RGBQUAD))
```

Use instead:

```py
('bmiColors', RGBQUAD * 256)
```

initialize like this:

```py
bmi = BITMAPINFO(BITMAPINFOHEADER(sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 0, 0, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                 (RGBQUAD * 256)(*[RGBQUAD(i,i,i,0) for i in range(256)]))
```

and set bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth and bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight whenever necessary.

Notes about using this in python with ctypes:

- Set .argtypes for every C function you import, wherever possible. Not doing so can throw exceptions, even when everything appears to be in order.
- Use classes and initialize BITMAPINFO like below: (code is incomplete!!!)

```py
import ctypes
from ctypes import c_ubyte, c_int, c_uint, c_void_p, POINTER, byref, sizeof
from ctypes.wintypes import WORD, DWORD, LONG, HDC

class RGBQUAD(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('rgbRed', c_ubyte),
        ('rgbGreen', c_ubyte),
        ('rgbBlue', c_ubyte),
        ('rgbReserved', c_ubyte)
    ]
class BITMAPINFOHEADER(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('biSize', DWORD),
        ('biWidth', LONG),
        ('biHeight', LONG),
        ('biPlanes', WORD), # 1
        ('biBitCount', WORD), # 8
        ('biCompression', DWORD), # BI_RGB = 0 for uncompressed format
        ('biSizeImage', DWORD), # 0
        ('biXPelsPerMeter', LONG), # 0
        ('biYPelsPerMeter', LONG), # 0
        ('biClrUsed', DWORD), # 0
        ('biClrImportant', DWORD) # 0
    ]
class BITMAPINFO(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('bmiHeader', BITMAPINFOHEADER),
        ('bmiColors', RGBQUAD * 256)
    ]

SetDIBitsToDevice = ctypes.windll.Gdi32.SetDIBitsToDevice
SetDIBitsToDevice.restype = BOOL # 0 if failed
SetDIBitsToDevice.argtypes = [HDC, c_int, c_int, DWORD, DWORD, c_int, c_int, c_uint, c_uint, c_void_p, POINTER(BITMAPINFO), c_uint]

bmi = BITMAPINFO(BITMAPINFOHEADER(sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 0, 0, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                 (RGBQUAD * 256)(*[RGBQUAD(i,i,i,0) for i in range(256)]))

SLM_HDC = CreateDC(None, monitor.info.szDevice, None, None)
data = np.array(...).astype(np.uint8)
data_p = data.ctypes.data_as(c_void_p)
SetDIBitsToDevice(SLM_HDC,
                  0, 0,
                  monitor.width(), monitor.height(),
                  0, 0,
                  0, monitor.height(),
                  data_p, byref(bmi), 0)
```

As for a complete way to do it in C++, here is a code example that creates an 8bit grayscale DIB and draws it on the primary monitor. Just compile it into an .exe and run it and you will see a diagonal grayscale pattern on your primary monitor. Explanations follow below.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <windows.h>

// tell linker where to resolve external dependencies
#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Gdi32.lib")

BITMAPINFO* CreateGreyscaleBITMAPINFO_P(int width, int height) {
    BITMAPINFO* pbmi = (BITMAPINFO*) std::malloc(offsetof(BITMAPINFO, bmiColors[256]));
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(pbmi->bmiHeader);
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight = height;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 8;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<256; i++) {
        pbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbRed = (BYTE)i;
        pbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbGreen = (BYTE)i;
        pbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbBlue = (BYTE)i;
        pbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbReserved = (BYTE)0;
    }
    return pbmi;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // to identify screen resolution correctly
    SetProcessDPIAware();

    // get HWND of full primary monitor to retrieve screen resolution and get HDC for drawing
    HWND desktop_HWND = GetDesktopWindow();
    LPRECT desktop_RECT = new RECT();
    if(GetWindowRect(desktop_HWND, desktop_RECT) == 0) { return 0; }
    int width = std::abs(desktop_RECT -> right - desktop_RECT -> left);
    int height = std::abs(desktop_RECT -> bottom - desktop_RECT -> top);
    HDC desktop_DC = GetDC(desktop_HWND);

    // define array with linearly increasing pixel value along the diagonal x=y
    // pixels have 8bit grayscale values from 0 (black) to 255 (white)
    BYTE* array = (BYTE*) std::malloc(sizeof(BYTE) * width * height);
    for(int i=0; i<height; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<width; j++) {
            array[i*width + j] = ((j + i) % 256);
        }
    }

    // initialize a BITMAPINFO instance and draw on desktop with SetDIBitsToDevice()
    const BITMAPINFO* bmip = CreateGreyscaleBITMAPINFO_P(width, height);
    int result = SetDIBitsToDevice(
        desktop_DC,
        0, 0, width, height,
        0, 0, 0, height,
        array, bmip, DIB_RGB_COLORS
        );

    // print out for debugging
    std::cout << "primary monitor resolution: " << width << " (width) x " << height << " (height)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "naive BITMAPINFO length (BYTES): " << sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + sizeof(RGBQUAD)*256
    << " vs. with windows macro offsetof(): " << offsetof(BITMAPINFO, bmiColors[256]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "bmiHeader.biSize: " << bmip->bmiHeader.biSize << std::endl;
    std::cout << "number of lines drawn on monitor: " << result << std::endl;
}
```

- Use malloc() to allocate the BITMAPINFO. Other examples have used alloca(), which causes the BITMAPINFO to be garbage collected before the DIB is drawn on the screen. If you are a physicist like me and don't give a hoot about programming details, always use malloc() and remember to manually free() the memory afterwards.
- I have no idea what is happenning with the HDC handles, here and in general.
- When setting the bmiColors, casting the integer counter i to (BYTE) looks unclean, but should be safe for i < 256. I did this to prevent a compiler warning about information loss.
- offsetof(BITMAPINFO, bmiColors[256]) and sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + sizeof(RGBQUAD)*256 give me the same result for 8 bits per pixel.

**Application idea:** This might be valuable to people drawing grayscale images on pixelated tools such as Liquid Crystal on Silicon [Spatial Light Modulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_light_modulator) (LCOS SLM). An SLM driver like this would eliminate the need for an additional thread/process to run a window on the SLM. A speed comparison with a PyQt5 window in a separate process (multiprocessing) on the SLM yielded an delay time that was lower by approx. 10 ms, probably because no cross-process communication was necessary. I am mentioning this for the search engines.